# Ограничить нагрузку на процессор

Tags: c#, wpf, subprocess

Пишу что-то вроде софтины для сервера, позволяющей удобно поднимать разные `bat`-ники ("сервера") из одного места, сохранять их настройки и аргументы и т.д.

Юзаю `c#` + `wpf`, вывожу `stdin` и `stderr` в модифицированный `RichTextBox`. Процессами управляю с помощью `Job Object`-ов.

И вот столкнулся с проблемой. Если где-то запущенный сервер упирается в бесконечный цикл вывода в консоль (а эти ошибки у программистов иногда бывают), то все виснет намертво.

Мало того, что дочерний процесс сам грузит систему, так еще и вывод в окошко програмки сильно замедляет работу.

В случае обычной `cmd.exe` достаточно было закрыть окно. Даже если в неё улетает куча вывода, все равно она вполне отзывчива к закрытию "по крестику". То ли буфер консоли работает очень быстро, то ли она как-то ограничивает ресурсы, потребляемые запущенным процессом.

Так вот. Можно ли как-то ограничить ресурсы дочернего процесса, дабы не происходило такого? Или все, что я могу сделать - лишь попытаться ускорить вывод сообщений в консоль/отключать их вывод, когда их слишком много?

Видел функционал, похожий на нужный, когда разбирался с `Job Object`-ами, однако не знаю, правильный ли это путь.

Честно, не знаю, какой код сюда можно добавить, так что говорите - приложу все, что будет нужно.

Comment: Просто обновляйте UI не на каждый чих, а, скажем, не более 25 раз в секунду. Для пользователя разницы никакой, а UI не будет виснуть

Comment: Консоль то отдельный мир, окошко консоли не связано напрямую с самим процессом, только со стандартными потоками ввода/вывода, а вывод в него наоборот очень медленный, по сравнению с графическими приложениями. Используйте буферизацию получаемых данных и выводите порциями.